# gcc/g++ using linkerflag "-lSDL2"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, sdl-2

acordingly to lazyfoos sdl tutorial 
https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/cli/index.php 
i setup sdl2. (and it runs with the given Terminal command) 
"g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -w -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL"

i cant remember the-lsdl2 flag and i don't know why i have to use it.
i also cant comprehend why gcc already know a SDL realatet option like -lsdl2.

how do people know they have to use this flag? i cant find anything usefull on this, people seem to just take it as a fact and tutorials didn't tell why to do so.

hope someone have time for this, i would be glad if i could gain knowledge to set up other libaries by my self next time

Comment: `-lSDL2` means *"link static library called `libSDL2.a`"*. So no, GCC doesn't know what SDL is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat to be pedantic, it doesn't necesserily mean static (and default on most systems is dynamic with fallback to static if no dynamic library found).

Answer (score 1):

Professionals do not need to remember compiler and linker flags. They use cross-platform pkgconfig

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2
```

For example it can be used in a shell

```
g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -w -o 01_hello_SDL `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
```

Comment: thanks for respone

just to be clear about the basics
how do i know wich linkerflag to add in my configfile? 
i was not able to find any official informatio about this